# Instantiate and initialize controller in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have a problem instanciating controller with Angular. I have a main controller **AlkeTypeDefListController** from which I want to dynamically create/remove controllers of type **AlkeTypeDefController**, so I have done that :

Code of **AlkeTypeDefListController**:

```
//  Create main controller          
Alke.controller('AlkeTypeDefListController', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller)
{
    var primitives = 
    [

    ];

    //  Add some properties to the scope
    angular.extend($scope,
    {
        typedefs        : primitives,
        addTypeDef      : function()
        {            
            var controller = $controller("AlkeTypeDefController", {$scope:$scope.$new()});
            $scope.typedefs.push(controller);
        }             
    });   
}]);
```

Code of **AlkeTypeDefController**:

```
//  Create main controller          
Alke.controller('AlkeTypeDefController', ['$scope', '$controller', function($scope, $controller)
{
    //  Add some properties to the scope
    angular.extend($scope,
    {
        name            : "New Type",
        fields          : [],
        addField        : function()
        {

        }  
    });  
}]);
```

The html code is this one:

```
<div id="typedefs-editor" ng:controller="AlkeTypeDefListController">
    <button ng:click="addTypeDef()">Add</button>
    <button>Remove</button>
    <div id="typedef-list">
        <ul class="list">
        <li ng:repeat="typedef in typedefs"><a href="#">{{typedef.name}}</a></li>                               
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem does not really come from the instantiation (which works fine), but from the initialization. In fact, when the new "li" appears when I push the "Add" button, the text "New type" (initialized in the controller) does not appear.

I think it is about the scope or something like that, but I can't really find how to fix this.

I wanted to know if this method seems correct, and also how could I fix the problem I have.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Reading the code, I understand that you want to create `typedefs` dynamically and those `typedef` items have to be controlled by an `AlkeTypeDefController`.

In that case I would create `AlkeTypeDefController` using `ng:controller` directive, so you don't need to create the controller programmatically, because then you would need to attached it to the view and that's just what the `ngController` directive does for you.

Notice `AlkeTypeDefListController` does not create a `AlkeTypeDefController` controller, this is done in the view

[**Demo on Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jF6Wn8al84NoXtMZig5P?p=preview)

**Controllers:**

```
.controller('AlkeTypeDefListController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var primitives = [];

    $scope.typedefs = primitives;

    $scope.addTypeDef = function() { 
      var typeDef = { name: 'New Type' };
      $scope.typedefs.push(typeDef);
    }
}])

.controller('AlkeTypeDefController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.addField = function() {
      alert('add Field');
    }
}]);
```

**View** *(notice how `ng-controller` directive is specified in `li` element):*

```
<div id="typedefs-editor" ng:controller="AlkeTypeDefListController">
  <button ng:click="addTypeDef()">Add</button>
  <button>Remove</button>
  <div id="typedef-list">

  <ul class="list">
      <li ng:repeat="typedef in typedefs" ng:controller="AlkeTypeDefController">
        <a href="#" ng-click="addField()">{{typedef.name}}</a>            
      </li>                               
  </ul>
</div>
```

In the code above, `ngRepeat` is going to create a new `$scope` for each `typedef`. `AlkeTypeDefController` then decorates that scope with functions and values.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

When you call $controller("AlkeTypeDefController") it will essentially call `new` on the AlkeTypeDefController constructor and give you back the return value **not the scope**. You are assign the `name` attrubute to the scope though so it is not being accessed in your html when you have `typedef.name`.

Try changing your AlkeTypeDefController to this:

```
Alke.controller('AlkeTypeDefController', function() {
    this.name = "New Type";
    this.fields = [];
    this.addField = function() {};
});
```

Then you can instantiate it with: `var controller = $controller("AlkeTypeDefController");` and you shouldn't need to worry about creating nested scopes.

Answer (score 2):

If I get what you're saying correctly then I think I'd try to leverage the power of a custom directive here instead of dynamically generating controllers.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4vAeVbH7rzBDlSkyOAoG)

Controller:

```
Alke.controller('alkeTypeDefListController', ['$scope', '$controller',
  function($scope, $controller) {
    var primitives = [];
    var addTypeDef = function() {
      $scope.typedefs.push({
        name: 'new name'
      });
    };
    var removeTypeDef = function(){
      $scope.typedefs.pop();
    };

    var properties = {
      typedefs: primitives,
      addTypeDef: addTypeDef,
      removeTypeDef: removeTypeDef
    };

    //  Add some properties to the scope
    angular.extend($scope, properties);
  }
]);
```

Directive:

```
Alke.directive('alkeTypeDef', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      typeDef: '=alkeTypeDef'
    },
    template: '<a href="#">{{typeDef.name}}</a>',
    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
      var properties = {
        fields: [],
        addField: function() {

        }
      };

      angular.extend(scope, properties);
    }
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='Alke'>
  <div id="typedefs-editor" ng-controller="alkeTypeDefListController">
    <button ng-click="addTypeDef()">Add</button>
    <button ng-click="removeTypeDef()">Remove</button>
    <div id="typedef-list">
      <ul class="list">
        <li alke-type-def='typedef' ng-repeat="typedef in typedefs"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want a controller then you can use one in the directive instead of a linking function.